# How to transfer Google G Suite in the sale of a site?

Tags: domains, email, google-workspace, gmail

We're in the process of selling a domain and going through all of the intricacies involved. We currently use Google's paid G Suite for things like email (gmail) and calendars etc.

I'm wondering what the best way to handle the G Suite piece. Ideally, I'd like former users to have access to their old emails though obviously they should not be able to send or receive new messages. It seems like Google has made that piece relatively easy by getting a downloadable archive of all data at http://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout . However, I'd like the new owners to NOT have access to old message from former users.

Is the best way to have the new owners create a separate G Suite account in their names and handle the domain authorization piece from scratch after the domain is transferred? The only downside here seems like it would be the bouncing - or interception - of new messages coming in to former accounts. Example, if joe@example.com is from the original owners, the new owners may be able to catch any messages coming to joe@example.com after the site is transferred. Doesn't seem like there's a way around that part.

Has any one else had to do this before? How did you handle it?

Comment: If you are selling the domain, then unless you come up with some sort of contractual agreement with the new owners, all email addresses become theirs.

Answer (score 2):

Have the buyers explicitly outlined they wish to continue with G-suite as their mail provider?

I'd leave it up to them to sort out their own email and hosting setup unless asked otherwise. Providing them with the addresses of importance so they can catch,create new accounts at their end should they need to.